# What's the right kind of weather stripping for this sliding door?

Tags: weatherstripping, sliding-glass-door

This door has a completely unobstructed gap from outside to inside along its entire length, albeit with a few 90-degree kinks.

I'm tempted to try sticking a rubber tubular type of weather strip onto the metal frame, but I could imagine it easily getting damaged or ripping as the door slides. What's the best type of product to use here?

It also looks like there may be a "slot" for a rubber flap or something to slide into, built into the metal door, but it's tiny and (obviously) empty right now.

[image: Sliding door with gap]

### Update

Thanks to the comments, I got some pile weather stripping that slides into the track:
[image: Gray Pile Weatherstrip, 9/32" x 1/8"]

But now what's the best way to secure it in place? Glue, or are there "end caps" for the track?

Comment: Brush type https://duckduckgo.com/?q=brush+door+seal+strip&t=h_&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fmaheshtradingoman.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F08%2Fdoor-brush.png

Comment: The slot at the bottom is where it goes. Various options, find one that looks right for your slot size and spacing: : **sliding glass door replacement weatherstripping**

Comment: You need a fuzzy type of weatherstrip like this: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07R7K58S7

Comment: Thank you, I've added to the question another question about how to secure this type of stripping in place as the door slides.